# Issue with navigation Bar when switching back to root View controller

Tags: ios, swift, navigationbar

I want my app to go back to main root view controller on button click, but when i press the button it goes but the navigation bar is disappeared. I have tried different solutions but no luck.

Comment: tell us about the app, the navigation controller, if/when you're hiding/showing the navigation bar, what the view hierarchy is when things go wrong, any error messages or interesting log output - we need something to go on...

Comment: Hello Wain, Actually my app is WEAR PASSBOOK in which i need to make the navigation bar static in all the views and in my end View i have a button saying "add tickets" which also saves my data to database and at the same time it pops to root view controller to add the tickets again, but unfortunately when i pop to root view controller the navigation bar disappears...

Comment: hey Wain. my app hierarchy is   splash screen -> root view page displaying button saying "add tickets" which opens photo library to select photos of tickets --> then the selected photo is displayed in another view where i have to crop the selected image and display the cropped image on another view where i also have a drop down menu and three text field stating select ticket category and then ticket type and the date and time and also have a button saying generate ..when i click on generate button it displays the inputted values on another view and in the last view i have a "add ticket" button

Comment: show the code for how you pop back. do all the views you show have a navigation bar then, until you pop?

Comment: @IBAction weak addTickets(sender: UIButton) {    self.navigationcontroller?.popTorootViewController(true, animated: true)}

Comment: Hey wain..Also i want that when i open photo library i dont want navigation bar to show

Comment: So you're hiding it and not re-showing it?

Comment: no, i am not hiding the navigation bar

Comment: Can you take a screenshot of the storyboard?

Comment: I have added my app screenshot

Answer (score 3):

Try this:
In your Root View Controller, add this code:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = false
}
```